# Create a roll-up summary field on Lookup without coding

Tags: workflow, process-builder, lookup, campaign, roll-up-summary

I have a custom object. From Campaign I have a lookup to the Custom object. What I want is to create a roll-up summary like feature on the Custom object but I can't use apex code. Can anyone suggest me if there is a way to achieve this using Process Builder or Workflow?

Comment: Use the dlrs app exchange package. Otherwise I do t believe you can do it without code. Why can't you use apex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of simple way to do it with Process Builder or Workflows, but if don't have the option of converting it to a Master-Detail relationship, and if you can't use Apex code, then you have a couple options:

1. If you want to create a Flow, check out the Salesforce Weekly how-to article mentioned on [this Community answer](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000476cAAA).
2. If you are looking for a ready-made solution, check out the suggestions on [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/93302/what-are-the-different-possible-ways-through-which-we-could-achieve-rollup-summa?rq=1). I believe you can find the one @Eric is referring to is by following the GitHub link in @crmprogdev's answer (there is a direct link to the AppExchange listing in the Features Summary section of the README). It seems the listing is private so you won't be able to search/browse for it.

I'd post the direct links myself, but I don't currently have enough rep to post more than two. So I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can install an application from appexchange to enable roll up feature for a look up relationship, it has a limitation though however its free on a positive side.

Secondly what worked for me was a simple report dashboard on the parent object.

Instead of making a field i showed the information through a summary report which i inserted to a chart and finally to the page layout of parent in lookup relationship.