# Roll-up summary field using PB + Flow

Tags: process-builder, visual-workflow, roll-up-summary

We have 2 objects - ObjectA and ObjectB. Object B has a lookup to ObjectA (so ObjectA is parent and ObjectB is child). We need to calculate no. of Active ObjectB records and show it in ObjectA record page. If it was M-D relationship, roll-up summary field was the solution, unfortunately it is not and it cannot be. We cannot have a report chart shown since this field is used for various other calculations.

So, we used Process Builder + Flow to calculate the no. of Active ObjectB records. On create/update of ObjectB, we pass the ObjectA__c reference to the flow, get all the ObjectB filtered on Status = Active and store it in a list variable. This happens in the loop element of flow and outside the loop element (after last), we update ObjectA's ActiveCount__c field.

References - https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000476cAAA
https://admin.salesforce.com/use-flow-builder-to-create-a-roll-up-summary-field
[Create a roll-up summary field on Lookup without coding](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/173275/create-a-roll-up-summary-field-on-lookup-without-coding)

This was all good when we tested by creating ObjectB records. But now when do proper testing, where we had 20 ObjectB records inserted, we got **DUPLICATE_VALUE: Maximum number of duplicate updates in one batch (12 allowed). Attempt to update Id more than once in this Api call: ObjectAId**

I am wondering if this is known issue. But as per documentations, Salesforce suggests that Flows are bulkified. Is this truly bulkified or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process Builder and Flows are bulkified (e.g. you can safely update a field on 200 records at once), but they can't handle the situation where a single record is updated a large number of times in the same transaction (more than 12). Unfortunately, Flows and Process Builder aren't great at updating parent records in a bulk pattern, and there's no way to make something that resembles a "map" in the Flow engine. You will need to use Apex, either by way of an InvocableMethod or just writing a trigger to enable mass updates in a safe manner.

Comment: So the "solution" of creating rollup summary using PB + Flow is not feasible?

Comment: @goabhigo Correct. Even if you got past this problem, you'd run in to others (e.g. Flows can't trigger on deletion of a record). Apex remains the only viable way to do this. Have you looked at [DLRS](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B45gWEAR)?

Comment: Yes, now looking into those as I read it somewhere (now not finding it, I will paste it again when I find it) that Flows are bulkified. I guess by bulkified they mean upto 12 records. Thank you Brian.

Comment: @goabhigo No, the Flow engine aggregates updates by advancing all elements in multiple updates at once, instead of executing one flow at a time. The 12 record limit is actually just related to the API limit for duplicate records per transaction.

Comment: @goabhigo The docs you're looking for are [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.216.0.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_admin_bulkification.htm#vpm_admin_bulkification).

Comment: If that's the case, then why can't it take all 20 records that I am inserting and handle it together? Why does it call 12+ times, and hence hitting that limit?

Comment: @goabhigo It does. However, it can't handle updating the *same* record 20 times. If you were doing something like updating 20 *different* records, it would handle it just fine.